# Semantic UI search custom data source

Tags: javascript, search, semantic-ui

API question here. I'm trying to use the [search](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/search.html) (autocomplete) module provided by Semantic UI. Looking at the API, I can't seem to find a way to use it with a custom function that loads the data async. All the examples I found use a fixed URL:

```
$('.ui.search').search({
  apiSettings: {
    url: '//api.github.com/search/repositories?q={query}'
  }
});
```

I'm trying to use this component with the google places api (`geocode`, what you see next is a thin promise wrapper I wrote to make the usage easier). I tried doing this according to the "Behaviors" part of the [docs](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/search.html#/usage):

```
$searchComponent.search({
  source: [],
  onSearchQuery(query) {
    // cancel original behaviour
    $searchComponent.search('cancel query'); 
    geocode({ input: query }).then(results => {
      // build suggestions
      const suggestions = results.map(place => ({ title: place.description }));
      // generate results for the newly created suggestions
      $searchComponent.search('generate results', suggestions);
      // finally show the autocomplete panel
      $searchComponent.search('show results');
    })
  },
})
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything for the `.search(method)` calls, cancel/generate/show doesn't seem to do anything. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it wasn't too clear, but here it is:

```
$searchComponent.api({
  responseAsync(settings, callback) {
    const query = settings.urlData.query;
    // make sure to transform result to an acceptable format
    asyncRequest(results => callback(result));
  }
}).search({ /* other config, like searchDelay */ })
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone lands here looking to completely customize adding results (like in the case of a cascading search), here's how to do that:

```
$searchComponent.search('add results',
    $searchComponent.search('generate results', { results: <<results>> })
);
```

In my case, I was setting a second level of results in `onSelect`.